# Arreglo de caracteres en Matlab

Tags: matlab

Buenas, alguien sabe como hacer un arreglo de cadenas, en que cada elemento es leído por teclado. Llevo esto pero no funciona, guarda los datos en una matriz 1xn y cada elemento es una matriz 1x1, sin embargo no se acceder a esos elementos.
Lo que intento es como un vector de cadenas normal en cualquier otro lenguaje, algo como esto en Java:

String[] V = new String[3]
V[0] = "Hola";
System.out.println(V[0]);

Este es mi intento de solución en MatLab R2012b.
clc;clear all;
flag = 1;
sw = 1;
cont = 0;
conexiones = struct([]);
while sw == 1
    if(flag == 1)
       n = input('Digite numero de conexiones:');
       flag = 0;
    elseif cont <= n
        cont = cont + 1;
        conexiones(cont).conexion = input('Digite conexion (Formato:  DesdeHacia): ','s');
    else
        sw = 0;
    end
end
%Intento leer el primer valor ingresado con esto
i = 0;
disp(conexiones(i).conexion)
%Pero me tira el siguiente error
%Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
%Error in WeShipCheap (line 19)
%disp(conexiones(i).conexion)

Answer (score 0):

while i <= n+1
    disp(conexiones(1,i).conexion)
    i = i + 1;
end

Con esta forma del Struct 'conexiones' logré hacerlo.

Output
Digite numero de conexiones:2
Digite conexion (Formato: DesdeHacia): A
Digite conexion (Formato: DesdeHacia): B
Digite conexion (Formato: DesdeHacia): C
A
B
C